# Error in YAML file regarding scanning a simple key

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I have an R markdown file with an input as .csv to be generated into a pdf file.

```
---
title: 
author:
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
params:
  csv_input: NULL    
---
```

While running the file, I get the following error:

> Warning: Error in yaml::yaml.load: Scanner error: while scanning a
> simple key at line 3, column 1 could not find expected ':' at line 4,
> column 1

Is there any way around this error? The YAML seems to be valid.

I checked the YAML which is valid. Entirely removed the YAML as well, which gives a similar error.

Comment: Previous issues on the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68415805/16730940

Comment: Or just check if there are white spaces after e.g. title: (there should be none)

Answer (score 1):

The YAML parser used within R markdown doesn't seem to be a good one. I recommend making the values for `title` and `author` explicit as parser doesn't seem to recognise the value indicator for one of them correctly (probably because the value indicator is not followed by a space):

```yaml
---
title: NULL
author: NULL
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
params:
  csv_input: NULL    
---
```